# how can i group by different dates and sum each data on group dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing to Ad Tracking Panel.

I have 3 table on my database,

**1- Campaigns**

```
id
orderID
name
startDate
endDate
goal
type
status
unitPrice
total
```

**2- Line Items**

```
lineItem_id
id
lineItemOrderID
lineItemName
lineItemStartDate
lineItemEndDate
lineItemStatus
lineItemType
lineItemGoal
```

**3- Line Items Statics**

```
statics_id
lineItem_id
inventoryID
inventoryName
impression
click
staticsDate
```

My Table Example:

[image: line item statics table example (data coming per 10 min)]

I want to like this result:

[image: this is i want photo]

How can I group by different dates and sum each data on group dates

My Example Code: (It's not working true, the values false)

```
SELECT inventoryNameGI, SUM(impressionGI), SUM(clickGI) 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT inventoryName AS inventoryNameGI, 
           MAX(impression) AS impressionGI, 
           MAX(click) AS clickGI 
    FROM   `line_items_statics` 
    WHERE  `lineItemID` = '5' 
    AND    staticsDate BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' 
                           AND '2017-07-03 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY `inventoryName` 
) AS toplamTablo
```

Comment: you need to use `GROUP BY` for you derived table again

Answer (score 0):

Try this - in your nested query, use `CONVERT` to convert `DATETIME` to `DATE` only.

```
SELECT INVENTORYID, SUM(IMPRESSION), SUM(CLICK), CONVERT(DATE,STATICSDATE)
FROM `line_items_statics` 
WHERE `lineItemID` = '5' 
  AND normalDate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-03' 
GROUP BY INVENTORYID,
         CONVERT(DATE,STATICSDATE)
```

Comment: Use CONVERT(DATE,STATICSDATE)